# UILabel get Frame width or height

Tags: swift, cgrect, cgsize

```
`lblAddress.frame.width`
`lblAddress.frame.size.width`
```

I have searched so many time but still i haven't point out...what is difference between `lblAddress.frame.width` AND  `lblAddress.frame.size.width`. it gives me same output..I don't know which one to use when?

please suggest some example so I can figure out whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are (almost) the same.
One is [width of CGRect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1454758-width), the other one is [width of CGSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgsize/1454308-width).

The only difference is that `frame.width` will always return positive values, as `frame.size.width` may return in some circumstances negative values.

I would use the shorthand `frame.width` directly if I only care about standardized geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Both frame and size have a width property. You might be getting confused because size is also a property of frame. It's like me asking you what color of shoes I have on but the next moment asking what color of shoes my feet have on, I'm asking the same thing, it just might be convenient for me to ask it one way or the other depending on my circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

To know more, you can look how CGRect structure is constructed.

```
struct CGRect {
  var origin: CGPoint
  var size: CGSize
}
```

and to add some extra functionality, an extension of CGRect is also provided by apple, like the following

```
extension CGRect {

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    public var height: CGFloat { get }

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    public var width: CGFloat { get }
}
```

Now to answer your question.
lblAddress.frame will return a CGRect

```
lblAddress.frame.width //This will use the extended functionality 
lblAddress.frame.size.width //this will use the actual struct

internally the width extension on CGRect will always use the same 
CGSize property from struct to give the width back and hence the same 
size property is accessed in both case, but the difference is the first 
one is standardized and hence only gives back positive values whereas 
the second will give the negative values as well.
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to find origin point use this code
here **ViewSend** is outlet of view

```
self.ViewSend.frame.origin.y
```

you want to find hight so use this code

```
self.ViewSend.frame.size.height
```

you want to find width so use this code

```
self.ViewSend.frame.size.width
```

Answer (score 0):

They are almost the same; however, `fram.width` is a get only value, but `frame.size.width` can be used to set or to get the value